Creating Tool Cut Animations
Is there a way to animate removal of material.  Let's say that I have a 'sheet' of material and I want to create an animation that would show an end result similar to this:

What I have tried is to take a Circle curve, add a geometry to it to get this:

However, when I use geometry nodes to animate this, the bevel disappears:

I assume this is because the Group Input is no longer connected, but I don't know what to do with that.
My questions for this are:

Am I on the right track?
Is there an easier way to do this if I am not
How do I animate a geometry node?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

I was trying something like @Jakemoyo in his answer as well, but there are several problems which occurred to me using the Arc node, so I decided on a mixed method, using a separate Bézier Circle object and the sheet object which holds a Geometry Nodes modifier.
So to get something that works like intended and still keep it editable, I added a Bézier Circle to the scene and a new Geometry Nodes nodetree to the sheet object.
In this nodetree I reference the Bézier Circle with an Object Info node set to Relative so that the location is taken into account. I convert it into a mesh with the Curve to Mesh node, as Profile Curve I choose the curve primitive Quadrilateral set to Rectangle. This way I have individual control over width of the cutout and the height if I want to make the sheet thicker and still be sure that the cutout goes through.
Before making a mesh from the curve, I plug the Object Info node into a Transform Geometry which I can use to change the scale of the circle so I do not have to do it on the original circle. By the way, instead of using Relative you could of course use the Transform Geometry to move the circle. This would be more convenient if you want to make several cutouts from just this one Bézier Circle.
To animate the cutting I use a Trim Curve node before the Curve to Mesh node. By animating the End value from 0 to 1 you get the animation. The resulting mesh will then be plugged into the second input of a Mesh Boolean node, with the sheet geometry from the Group Input in the first socket. So this would be the basic setup, I did not animate the End directly but with an extra Value which I explain afterwards why:

This is all quite nice as long as the circle is not closed, i.e. the End value does not reach 1. But as soon as it does, you'll see that there is something remaining at the end:

You can use a Merge by Distance node but it will only work correctly if the Fill Caps option on the Curves to Mesh node was disabled. However this is needed for the Boolean operation to work as long as the circle is not closed.
So that's why I used a separate animated Value node. Apart from using it to trim the end, I'm also plugging it into a Compare node set to Less Than with 1 as second value. The Result I plug into the Fill Caps input. As long as the trimming end value is less than 1, the result is True and therefore the caps are filled. When it reaches 1, the result is False and the caps are open and merge without problems. Here is the modified nodetree:

And here is the result, you can change the cutout anytime by changing the size of the circle with the Scale value on the Transform Geometry node, changing the width of the cutout with the Width value in the Quadrilateral node and if you change the thickness of the sheet you can also adjust the Height of the Quadrilateral if it is not thick enough to cut through. Of course you could add more complex stuff like automatically changing the hieght according to the thickness etc. and make everything more convenient. This is just a simple setup for tweaking those things manually.



Thanks, this is what I ended up doing and got a really good result for what I am trying to do.  Thanks a lot!

I want to make my life more difficult by not using Mesh Boolean! XD
Using Blender 4.1, here's a solution without using Mesh Boolean node:

Result:

I attached the complete setup to also cover the bottom of the object


That's a good way to do it as well.

I truly have a lot to learn about these geometry nodes...it's amazing what you can do with them.  Thanks for this!

I think you've got it alright, your problem is that you're kind of mixing techniques, GN/NonGN, Curve/NonCurve etc. Adding geometry via the Object Data panel to a curve essentially "converts" it to a mesh under the hood. So doing mesh type operations like Boolean etc can be a little problematic. If you just do all the operations via GN it's easier IMO.

End result:


Excellent, thanks for the help!
